# Gimp scale tool always defaults to 'Dont preserve aspect ratio'

Tags: gimp, scale

Whenever i pick the scale tool and click on a selected region, the scale tool defaults to "dont preserve aspect ratio". If I jerk the mouse slightly when I first click on the selection with the scale tool, it usually warps a little bit. So every time I use it, I have to be extra careful to apply my first click without moving the mouse at all. It gets old, fast. How can I make sure that the scale tool starts off with preserve aspect ratio right off the bat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the option in the Scale tool, then go to `Edit>Preferences>Tool options` and click `Save tools options now`.

**Warning**: Of course this saves all the options of all the tools, plus the current colors, pattern, gradient, brush, dynamics, so make sure everything is as you want it before clicking.

Comment: So, I can just open a random file, only change this, save; and ill be fine?

Comment: Yo don't even need to open a file. Just start Gimp to have you initial state.